# Output Voltage of a Current Mode Controlled Flyback Converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, flyback, duty-cycle

I'm trying to use the [NCP1014](https://www.onsemi.com/products/power-management/ac-dc-controllers-regulators/offline-regulators/ncp1014) (65kHz) to make a flyback converter. I'm using coilcraft's transformer [B0570-BL](https://www.coilcraft.com/ncp101x.cfm) which is specifically designed for the NCP1014, with turns ratio 1:0.06 or 16.67:1. I intend to take in narrow european mains (actually, narrow Indian mains, 230VAC ~ 310VDC) and generate 1A@12V.

Using the 'textbook' flyback controller equations, I get a duty cycle requirement using that transformer of:

```
dctyp = N * Vout / Vin
      = 16.67 * 12.7 / 310 = 0.68
```

The datasheet of the NCP1014 uses its eq.24 on page 17 for operating duty cycle,

```
dc = Ip * Lp / Vin * Tsw
   = (450mA * 3.4mH) / (310V * 15.38us)
   = 0.321
```

The two duty cycles are very different. I understand why this is - the duty cycle for the
NCP1014 is set only by the time it takes for primary current to ramp to 450mA. What 
I can't work out is how the output regulation will work for this, given that the 
required duty cycle is *more* than the cutoff.

Given the duty cycle the NCP1014 will cut off at, will the output have enough energy 
to sustain a stable 12V output? How does one make sure this will work for a given output voltage (12V, in this case)

I have attempted to work though the datasheet in nearly its entirety to the best of my understanding. I have put it up [here](http://static.chintal.in/ncp1014.html), if it will help.

Comment: The definition of the duty ratio you give is for a continuous-conduction-operated (CCM) flyback converter. For the (high) input voltage you state, it is very likely the converter operates in discontinuous conduction mode (DCM) and the duty ratio definition for a given output voltage is different. The second formula states the maximum peak current of this switcher which is unlikely to be hit in normal operation. It is however a good starting point to see what maximum duty ratio you may expect in DCM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When operating in DCM (and that is what this design does), the voltage transfer is this: -

$$\dfrac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}} = N\cdot D\sqrt{\dfrac{R_L}{2\cdot F_{SW}\cdot L_P}}$$

Where: -

- \$N\$ is the turns ratio as a fraction i.e. 1/16.67 (0.06) for your case
- \$D\$ is the duty cycle percentage
- \$R_L\$ is your load resistance on the secondary
- \$F_{SW}\$ is your switching frequency i.e. 65 kHz
- \$L_P\$ is your primary inductance

The important thing to note is that the voltage transfer is load dependent unlike when operating in CCM.

> *How does one make sure this will work for a given output voltage (12V,
>   in this case)*

Try plugging in the numbers into the above equation but do take account of what your maximum and minimum loading values are.